# Recuperar datos de una fila en una tabla

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo esta tabla en un JSP y estoy intentando sacar todos los valores de la fila al pulsar el botón con JavaScript.

```
<table id="myTable">
<c:if test="${not empty conversaciones}">
   <tr class="titulo">
     <th>Id Conversacion</th>
     <th>Inicio conversacion</th>
     <th>Nombre agente</th>
     <th>Nombre cola origen</th>
     <th>ID cola origen</th>
     <th>Nombre cliente</th>
     <th>Email cliente</th>
     <th>Asunto email</th>
     <th>ID cola aparcamiento participante</th>
     <th></th>
   </tr>

<c:forEach items="${conversaciones}" var="conversacion">

<tr class="fila" onclick="myFunction(this)">
     <td><a href="javascript:;" id="enlaceEnviar"><c:out value="${conversacion.conversationId}" /></a></td>
     <td><c:out value="${conversacion.conversationStartFormat}" /></td>
     <td><c:out value="${conversacion.agentName}" /></td>
     <td><c:out value="${conversacion.colaName}" /></td>
     <td><select name="destino" class="select">
         <option value="">--</option>
         <option value="1">--PRUEBAS--Origin queue 1</option> 
         <option value="2">--PRUEBAS--Origin queue 2</option> 
     </select></td>

     <td><c:out value="${conversacion.customerName}" /></td>
     <td><c:out value="${conversacion.customerEmail}" /></td>
     <td><c:out value="${conversacion.asunto}" /></td>
     <td><c:out value="${conversacion.aparcamientoId}" /></td>
     <td><input class="boton" type="button" value="Desaparcar correo"/></td>
</tr>

</c:forEach>
</c:if>
</table>
```

Mi problema está al intentar sacar el valor del select, lo estoy intentando con:

```
var row_index = $(this).parent().index();
alert("row_index" + row_index);

var x = parseInt(row_index, 10);

indice = document.getElementsByName("destino")[x].selectedIndex;
if( indice == null || indice == 0 ) {
alert("NO HAY VALORES");
}else{
alert("HAY VALORES");
};
```

pero al pulsar el botón, me sale siempre el valor 9 en row_index, además no me coge el valor de x para pasarlo al índice. ¿Puede ayudarme alguien con esto, por favor?

Comment: Hola Davinia. ¿Puedes proveer de un ejemplo donde poder probar tu codigo y ver qué puede estar pasando? ¿has hecho logs o usado el modo de depuración? Mira [ask] y [mcve] para añadir más informacion a la pregunta.  (¿Por qué borraste la pregunta y la volviste a formular? Puedes modificarla pulsando en  [edit]) Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, no puedo poner un ejemplo donde probar el código porque es una integración con otra plataforma y los datos para rellenar la tabla vienen de un servlet aparte. Sí, he hecho logs y he usado el modo de depuración. Borré la pregunta porque no me dejaba editarla, ya que al principio puse el código mal.

Comment: De todas formas ya he solucionado el problema usando      var row_index = $(this).parent().parent().index();             
alert("row_index" + row_index);
var y = parseInt(row_index, 10);
x = y - 2;

Comment: Hola @Davinia. Por favor no agregues "solucionado" en el título (esto no es un foro). Lo mejor sería que publiques tu propia respuesta abajo y la aceptes